# Save state of visible divs in gridview

Tags: javascript, .net

I have a hiddenfield thats meant to store information about the visibility for a div contained in a gridview.

```
<asp:HiddenField id="divhidden" runat="server" />
```

I then set the value in javascript.

```
weekrow.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = 'visible';
```

I can see it working up to the point of a postback, where the value is cleared. This seems to work when I try the same concept outside of the gridview, but for some reason maybe the databound clears the value? Is there anyway to keep the value in the hiddenfield between postbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gridview cleared the values on the hiddenfields. Therefore it couldn't be used to store the values of my divs beeing hidden or not.

I solved it by creating a div "divhidden" that adds hiddenvalues that can be used to set the visibility edited by my javascript.

The information on which divs are hidden are now stored between postbacks in these hidden values.

aspx-page:
    hiddenDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
    hiddenDiv.ID = "hiddenValuesDiv";
    PlanningForm.Controls.Add(hiddenDiv);

```
      Label weekLabel = row.FindControl("weeknr") as Label;
      if (weekLabel != null && PlanningForm.FindControl("visiblediv" + weekLabel.Text) == null) {

          HiddenField divvisible = new HiddenField();
          divvisible.ID = "visiblediv" + weekLabel.Text;
          //Open the first two divs
          if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
              if(openDivCount < 2)
              divvisible.Value = "block";
              openDivCount++;
          }
          hiddenDiv.Controls.Add(divvisible);
      }
```

And the javascript code:

```
function expandcollapse(obj, row) {
var hidden = document.getElementById(GetClientId('visible' + obj));
var warningonweek = weekrow.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].getElementsByTagName('img')
if (div.style.display == "none") {
    div.style.display = "block";
    ....
}
else {
    div.style.display = "none";
    ....
}
```

}